# How to check if a geofence event is triggered by a mock location?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

The `Location` class has [isFromMockProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()) method to check if a location was generated by a mock location provider. I cannot find similar method in the [GeofencingEvent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent) class. Is there a reliable way to find out if a geofence event is triggered by a mock location provider?

Comment: I would expect the `Location` returned by [`getTriggeringLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent.html#getTriggeringLocation()) to contain what you're looking for...

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede You are right. That was really easy.